# R: Calculating total hours from Dates and Times

Tags: r, calculated-columns, date-arithmetic

First time question and new to R.

I am pulling data from a SQL server and putting into a R data table (SAP). I am trying to calculate the total hours from 4 columns (StartDate, FinDate, StartTime, FinTime).

[image: DataTable]

I have tried this to calcute from datatable (SAP), but not getting what I want.

```
SAP$hours <- with(SAP,
                  difftime(c(ActStartDate, ActStartTime), 
                           c(ActFinDate, ActFinTime),
                           units = "hours") )
```

I would like to have the total hours added to the data Table or a vector assigned the total hours.

This is how I would do in excel:

Hours = ((End_Date+End_Time)-(Start_Date+Start_Time))*24

Comment: Welcome to SO! This community has a few [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [norms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and following them will help you get a good answer to your question. In particular, it’s best to avoid using images of code/data and [here’s why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  Note that you can quickly get your data out of your R session and onto SO by calling `dput(my_df)` and copy/pasting the result.  If your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Comment: Have you checked the type of the data in your columns? - you may need to call `as.Date()` on them before `difftime` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#sample data:
df <- data.frame(startdate = c("2018-08-23 00.00.00"), 
                 enddate = c("2018-08-24 00.00.00"), 
                 starttime = c("23:00:00"), 
                 endtime = c("23:30:00"))

#This will first combine date(after extracting the date part) and time and
#then convert it to a date time object readable by R. 
df$sdt <- as.POSIXct(paste(substr(df$startdate, 1, 10), 
                           df$starttime, 
                           sep = " "), 
                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")    

#Same for end date time
df$edt <- as.POSIXct(paste(substr(df$enddate, 1, 10), 
                           df$endtime, 
                           sep = " "), 
                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df$diff <- difftime(df$edt, df$sdt, units = "hours")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I ended up doing this with your inputs and it worked.

```
    # make it a data table
    SAP <- data.table(SAP)

    # only select some columns of interest
    SAP <- SAP[, .(Equipment, Order, ActStartDate, ActStartTime, ActFinDate, ActFinTime)]

    # generate start / end as POSIX, 
    # this code assumes that start date from SAP is always like 2018-05-05
    # so 10 chars as YYYY-MM-DD
    # if needed add time zone information, e.g as.POSIXct(..., tz = 'UTC')
    SAP[, start := as.POSIXct(paste0(substring(ActStartDate, 1, 10), ActStartTime))]
    SAP[, end := as.POSIXct(paste0(substring(ActFinDate, 1, 10), ActFinTime))]

    # calculate duration
    SAP[, duration := difftime(end, start, units = "hours")]
```